# Iteration does not count correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, binary

I have written the following block:

```
number = 12

def checkio(number):
    count = 0
    for n in bin(number):
         print n
         if n == 1:
             count += 1
    print count


checkio(number)
```

The output I get is:

```
0
0
b
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
```

I can't understand why I'm able to iterate through `n` in the binary number and `print` it, but my `if` won't work correctly and won't add to my `count` variable.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate through the string produced by `bin`, each character is itself a one-character string. So the reason this doesn't work is, simply:

```
1 != '1'
```

You will need to convert the characters back into integers to compare (be aware that `int('b')` won't work!), or compare to a string:

```
if n == '1':
```

Answer (score 0):

The check should be "if n == '1'".